# Permutation Distributions from Independent Random Variables

Tags: probability, permutations, random-variables, independence

I'm interested by a problem related to the ranking of random variables. Consider a ranking function, denoted as $G: \mathbb{R}^n \to S_n$, which takes a set of $n$ real numbers as input and produces their corresponding ranking (a permutation). For instance, $G(0, 10, 5, 7) = \{4, 1, 3, 2\}$ reflects the ranking of these numbers.

Now, let $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ be independent (though not necessarily identical) random variables distributed over $\mathbb{R}$. The question that I am interested in is: What are the possible distributions over $S_n$ that can be generated under the assumption of independence, and can these distributions be systematically classified?

Although I'm not well-versed in probability distributions over permutations, I suspect that there might be existing literature on this topic. However, my unfamiliarity with the field has hindered my ability to effectively search for relevant results. I would appreciate any guidance or insights that could point me in the right direction (e.g., a book about this topic).